# How to enable capitalization on the virtual keyboard for an Android Compose TextField?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I've recently started moving to Compose to make my UIs in Android. So far I like it, but I'm still struggling to find the right documentation sometimes. So I'm sorry if this question is very obvious!

In the app I'm currently working on, I have a `TextField` that is used to enter the title of a message. Everything works fine, except that the virtual (on-screen) keyboard doesn't by default enable caps lock for the first letter. **Is it possible to enable caps lock on the virtual keyboard for a `TextField`, and if so, how?** It's only necessary for the first character in the `TextField` (or in a sentence, it's a title field so there should only be one sentence), if a user wants to capitalize more they are welcome to do it themselves :) So what I'm basically looking for is the Compose version of the `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` XML-attribute of the EditText.

My code for the `TextField` is below. Some background in case that helps: the `TextField` is inside a `Stack` which also holds a `Text`. I use that to display a hint in case the `TextField` is empty. The `Stack` is inside a `Column`, which in it's turn is inside a `VerticalScroller` that wraps the whole screen. I'm using Android Studio 4.0 Canary 7.

Thanks very much in advance!

```
// Model saving the current state of the TextField
val modelTitle = +state{EditorModel()}
// Context (aka the Activity) necessary to get the focus and input method manager
val context = +ambient(ContextAmbient)
// Input Method Manager, to hide the keyboard
val imm = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

TextField {
    value = modelTitle.value,
    modifier = ExpandedWidth.wraps(Spacing(5.dp)),
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        color = Color.White,
        fontSize = 30.sp
    ),
    onValueChange = {
        modelTitle.value = it
    },
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
    onImeActionPerformed = {
        // Get the view currently in focus, or make one
        var view = (context as Activity).currentFocus
        if(view == null)
            view = View(context)

        // Use the view to hide the keyboard
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    },
}
```

Comment: Do you want text field input value to be capitalize or virtual keyword with capitalize value ?

Comment: Ah, that's a bit ambiguous indeed :) I edited the question to make it clearer. What I would like is a behaviour similar to the XML EditText attribute `android:inputType="textCapSentences"`. So the user is still allowed to disable caps lock and start with a lower case letter, but it's not the default. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

You can use `keyboardOptions`and `KeyboardCapitalization` (FYI I'm on alpha09):

```kotlin
TextField(
    ...,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences)
)
```

Answer (score 8):

With the `1.0.0-beta02` you can use the **`keyboardOptions`** attribute:

```
   TextField(
         keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences)
   )
```